# how to find most frequent string element in numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is their any way to find most frequent string element in numpy ndarray?

```
A= numpy.array(['a','b','c']['d','d','e']])


result should be 'd'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want a numpy answer you can use `np.unique`:

```
>>> unique,pos = np.unique(A,return_inverse=True) #Finds all unique elements and their positions
>>> counts = np.bincount(pos)                     #Count the number of each unique element
>>> maxpos = counts.argmax()                      #Finds the positions of the maximum count

>>> (unique[maxpos],counts[maxpos])
('d', 2)
```

Although if there are two elements with equal counts this will simply take the first from the `unique` array.

With this you can also easily sort by element count like so:

```
>>> maxsort = counts.argsort()[::-1]
>>> (unique[maxsort],counts[maxsort])
(array(['d', 'e', 'c', 'b', 'a'],
      dtype='|S1'), array([2, 1, 1, 1, 1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> A = numpy.array([['a','b','c'],['d','d','e']])
>>> Counter(A.flat).most_common(1)
[('d', 2)]
```

Extracting the `'d'` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: how to get at the desired dimension with out using .flat?@NPE

Comment: @nils: Not sure I understand your question. You feed an array of any shape and dimensions, and get back a scalar.