# Count of values in numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Is there any way to do the following in purely numpy (or opencv)?

```
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
counts = defaultdict(int)
for row in img:
    for val in row:
        counts[tuple(val)] += 1
```

The problem is that `tuple(val)` can obviously be one of 2^24 different values so having an array for every possible value is not possible since it'd be gigantic and mostly zeros, so I need a more efficient data structure.

Comment: Sparse matrix perhaps

Comment: you could convert the hxwx3 matrix into a hxw by bitshifting two colors up and summing.  Then using [np.unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)  You could also probably use tuples instead of bitshifting and adding but that would probably make np.unique run a lot slower...

Comment: @Hammer Yes that seems easy enough to convert into a 32bit 2d matrix. But how does `np.unique` give me how often each color appears in the array?

Comment: @Voo pass the return_inverse flag and then just check the length of the indices list you get back for each unique value

Comment: See the question from earlier today [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909167/how-to-find-most-frequent-string-element-in-numpy-ndarray). He was looking for the maximum occurrence, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Yeah I was wrong, you don't check the length, you bincount

Comment: I would assume you want to stay in numpy because of efficiency.  I am curious how much faster this would actually run than using your approach in the question or collections.Counter.  The bitshifting and summing might be more cost than it is worth...

Comment: @Hammer Got it, yeah I'll do some performance tests, but since I have to do some more operations on the data afterwards having the counts in a numpy datastructure is probably going to help offset the initial conversion costs. Also I'm going to see if I can get opencv to give me the frame in the right format to begin with.

Comment: [np.frombuffer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) might help there.  If it is bgra you could just interpret it as a 32 bit int.  I don't know if 24 bit ints exist in numpy...

Comment: You don't need to do anything to the data: view it as a 24 bit void dtype, then run the `np.unique` / `np.bincount` combo on it. You'll need to view the return of `np.unique` as 3 `uint8`s and reshape it to `(-1, 3)` to make sense of the data, but it will be much faster, as nothing is done aside from viewing the exact same memory in a different way.

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839303/find-and-delete-from-more-dimensional-numpy-array/16840350#16840350) there is an example of using `np.void`, in your case it would be something like `np.dtype((np.void, 3*dtype(np.uint8).itemsize))` or even `np.dtype((np.void, 3))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

- convert the image to an one-dim array with dtype=uint32
- `sort()` the array
- use `diff()` to find all the position that color changed.
- use `diff()` again to find the count of every color.

the code:

```
In [50]:
from collections import defaultdict
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")

In [51]:
%%time
counts = defaultdict(int)
for row in img:
    for val in row:
        counts[tuple(val)] += 1
Wall time: 1.29 s

In [53]:
%%time
img2 = np.concatenate((img, np.zeros_like(img[:, :, :1])), axis=2).view(np.uint32).ravel()
img2.sort()
pos = np.r_[0, np.where(np.diff(img2) != 0)[0] + 1]
count = np.r_[np.diff(pos), len(img2) - pos[-1]]
r, g, b, _ = img2[pos].view(np.uint8).reshape(-1, 4).T
colors = zip(r, g, b)
result = dict(zip(colors, count))
Wall time: 177 ms

In [49]:
counts == result
Out[49]:
True
```

If you can use pandas, you can call `pandas.value_counts()`, it's implemented in cython
with hash table.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way around this, if the image is stored in "chunky" format, i.e. the color planes dimension is the last, and this last dimension is contiguous, is to take a `np.void` view of every 24bits pixel, then run the result through `np.unique` and `np.bincount`:

```
>>> arr = np.random.randint(256, size=(10, 10, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
>>> dt = np.dtype((np.void, arr.shape[-1]*arr.dtype.itemsize))
>>> if arr.strides[-1] != arr.dtype.itemsize:
...     arr = np.ascontiguousarray(arr)
... 
>>> arr_view = arr.view(dt)
```

The contents of `arr_view` look like garbage:

```
>>> arr_view [0, 0]
array([Â], 
      dtype='|V3')
```

But it's not us that have to understand the content:

```
>>> unq, _ = np.unique(arr_view, return_inverse=True)
>>> unq_cnts = np.bincount(_)
>>> unq = unq.view(arr.dtype).reshape(-1, arr.shape[-1])
```

And now you have the unique pixels and their counts in those two arrays:

```
>>> unq[:5]
array([[  0,  82,  78],
       [  6, 221, 188],
       [  9, 209,  85],
       [ 14, 210,  24],
       [ 14, 254,  88]], dtype=uint8)
>>> unq_cnts[:5]
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Interestingly enough when measuring the different performance characteristics I get the following timings: naive ~15s, your solution ~4s, HYRY's approach ~0.4s. Quite surprised myself but apparently numpy is just way more efficient when working on natural sized integers that the additional pass-through is easily amortized. The downside being that it takes more than double the memory, but that's acceptable in my case.